# Using jTDS to connect to SQL Server 2012 availability group listener

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-server-2012, high-availability, jtds

I am working on a legacy project that uses jTDS to connect to SQL server. The client wants us to support SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn. one key requirement is the ability of our application to  automatically reconnect to secondary server in event of failover.

unfortunately, jTDS 3.0 does not support AlwaysOn. I have 2 options

1. use MS JDBC (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11774)
2. Write a wrapper that returns the connection string after checking the status of the active node

option 1 is serious engineering(heavy testing) effort. Has anyone tried option 2 or something else to use jTDS to connect to SQL 2012 avilablity group listener? if yes please provide some guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tweaking my DAL to handle specific SQL Errors, I was able to retry all the transactions whenever there was a Availability group fail-over.

I am handling the following SQL Errors

Severity 16 DB error codes (10054, 233, 232, 2812, 64, 3906) 
Severity 14 Db error codes (983, 922, 945)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but what connection string did you use to connect to the listener? Did you specify MultiSubnetFailover=True?

Comment: that would be for MS's JDBC driver. using the MultiSubnetFailover=True helps in retrying the connection in case of failure faster. the only advantage of it is that the downtime is hard to perceive for app users (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558121(v=sql.110).aspx)