# How to connect to MS Sql Server failover cluster using Glassfish JDBC connection pooling

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, glassfish

I'm trying to connect to a failover cluster using the glassfish connection pooling. My resource type is `XADataSource`, classname `JtdsDataSource`. My additional properties are:

- User
- DatabaseName
- Password
- PortNumber
- serverName

All of these work for connecting normally but I have been unable to find the correct property name for connecting to the mirror for this database. On the basis of this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175484.aspx I've tried  `FailoverPartner` and `Failover_Partner` but during testing where the primary database was brought down while the server was running glassfish was still trying to connect to the primary.

With nothing else to go on regarding this particular scenario, I ask what specific property name is used to specify my mirror database in Glassfish.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting of database mirroring has little to do with Glassfish in particular, it must be supported by the JDBC driver.

It seems that you are using JTDS driver to connect to MS SQL. Unfortunately, it [does not support database mirroring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651383/using-jtds-to-connect-to-sql-server-2012-availability-group-listener) - some guys in this SO question discuss possibilities to create a wrapper around this driver, if you cannot afford to switch the driver.

You may be better off with the official driver from Microsoft. It should support [failoverPartner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342332%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) parameter in connection string.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the length of time it took to respond. Switching the driver has worked, I can now access the mirror db when failover occurs. Thanks again for your help!